# Calling WCF service function with vb script having moniker gives error as: Failed to do mex retrieval

Tags: wcf, vbscript

I have a service running , which I am accessing from the client application using Vb Script.

The code in the client app. is 
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Users\ade1kor\Desktop\test.vbs");

the test.vbs is like : ...

```
Dim addr 

addr = "service:mexAddress=""net.tcp://localhost:8523/Service1/mex"","
addr = addr + "address=""net.tcp://localhost:8523/Service1"","
addr = addr + "contract=""IService1"", contractNamespace=""WcfServiceLibrary1"","
addr = addr + "binding=""NetTcpBinding_IService1"", bindingNamespace=""http://tempuri.org/"""

Dim service
Set service = GetObject(addr)

MsgBox (service.GetData(3))
```

.....

But when I run the client an error dialog appears telling

`"Error:Failed to do mex retrieval:Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:8523//Service1//mex'..
Code:   800401E4"`

I dont know what to do... if anyone have any idea,kindly share

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I wasn't aware of this functionalty before. However, it seems you aren't referencing the COM classid as shown in this [MSDN article with sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752245.aspx). The contractType value looks to be missing from your code. It should look something like this:

`contractType={9213C6D2-5A6F-3D26-839B-3BA9B82228D3}`

where the GUID is the COM classid from having registered the client COMInterop enabled .NET assembly.

Comment: Thanks a lot; that helped.                                                            Link "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752245.aspx" can also be referred for other installations required.

Comment: Glad to help, my current client has a major investment in old COM-based PowerBuilder apps and now I can recommend another integration option for calling WCF services. Thanks!